# Compile error when initializing class member std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I am trying to create a class with an std::function member:

```
# include<functional>

class Widget {
public:
  std::function<int(double)> call_foo;

  Widget(std::function<int(double)> call_func)
    : call_foo(call_func)
  {};

};
```

However, when I try to initialize the class my code fails:

```
const int f(double x){
  if(x > 5.0){
    return 22;
  }
  return 17;
}

int main()
{
  std::function<int(double)> f1 = f;
  Widget p(f1);

}
```

The full set of errors is below:

```
 tmp/ccDoRHCh.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
widget.cpp:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
widget.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccDoRHCh.o:(.rodata._ZTIPFidE[_ZTIPFidE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__pointer_type_info'
/tmp/ccDoRHCh.o:(.rodata._ZTIFidE[_ZTIFidE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__function_type_info'
/tmp/ccDoRHCh.o:(.eh_frame+0xab): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am compiling with C++ 11 enabled.

Comment: Did you do `#include <functional>`?

Comment: @ex-bart You were correct that I forgot this include but the code still will not compile. There seems to be some kind of linker error?

Comment: @Brian I thought I had constructed an SSCCE. I am not sure how I could make this example any more minimal other than function f's function body, which is already quite stripped down? The code above is my entire file and should be self contained.

Comment: It looks like you're typing gcc at the command line instead of g++.

Comment: Slow down and read some information on how to build basic C++11 programs. For example, using `g++` (not `gcc`).

Answer (score 2):

Chances are either you forgot

```
#include <functional>
```

or you'r not compiling in C++11 mode.

Comment: you were correct, but even after the inclusion of functional, this still will not compile.